# "Internal error on generating report." error occurs

Tags: google-search-appliance

When generating a Search Report for any collection, the report status appears as "Complete". However, when i attempt to View or Export the report i am getting an error indicating "Internal error on generating report.".
I am able to 'Update' the report to regenerate the report however, the same issue occurs when i view/edit the new report.

Event logs don't show anything other than the report generation event.

Comment: Hey joenco, welcome to Stack Overflow! In order to help you in the best possible way, we need more datails abouot the issue you're facing. Please add things to your question like what exactly you have tried (step by step), but exactly doesn't work and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that's a known bug that's fixed in one of the most recently released patches. Log a ticket with Google and they'll give you the details and should be able to give you a support script that you can run for a temporary fix until you apply the patch.